# Symfony2 Pagination Controller Error

Tags: php, symfony, pagination

I am trying to paginate a list of products but I'm coming across an error.  Here is the `indexAction` from the `ProductsController.php` file.

```
public function indexAction($page)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entities = $em->getRepository('IbwTazJazBundle:Products')->findAll();

        $total_products = $em->getRepository('IbwTazJazBundle:Products')->countActiveProducts($entities->getId());
        $products_per_page = $this->container->getParameter('max_products_on_homepage');
        $last_page = ceil($total_products / $products_per_page);
        $previous_page = $page > 1 ? $page - 1 : 1;
        $next_page = $page < $last_page ? $page + 1 : $last_page;
        $entities->setActiveProducts($em->getRepository('IbwTazJazBundle:Products')->getActiveProducts($entities->getId(), $products_per_page, ($page - 1) * $products_per_page));



        return $this->render('IbwTazJazBundle:Products:index.html.twig', array(
            'entities' => $entities,
            'last_page' => $last_page,
            'previous_page' => $previous_page,
            'current_page' => $page,
            'next_page' => $next_page,
            'total_products' => $total_products

        ));
    }
```

When I refresh the page, I'm getting a message `Error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object` and it is quoting the line below:

```
$total_products = $em->getRepository('IbwTazJazBundle:Products')->countActiveProducts($entities->getId());
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to ensure that $entities is an object before you can call a method on it... So after assigning the value (I.e. `$entities = $em->getRepository('IbwTazJazBundle:Products')->findAll();`) check `is_object($entities)`- if that is false-y then you have an issue

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `$em->getRepository('IbwTazJazBundle:Products')->countActiveProducts($entities->getId());` ?

Comment: Try to take al look at Knp Paginator Bunlde https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle

Answer (score 0):

`findAll()` return a Collection of object. It mean even if you have only one object in your table, it will return an array of 1 Element like `[0=> Product]`

As your table is named products, I doubt you have only one row.